# AMP Page Reading Progress For Content Only

Tags: amp-html

I found this example for reading progress on AMP page on [this pen](https://codepen.io/aghassemi/pen/MxQxZR)

#### Code

```
<amp-position-observer
  intersection-ratios="0"
  viewport-margins=100vh
  on="scroll:pogressAnimation.seekTo(percent=event.percent)"
  layout="nodisplay"
></amp-position-observer>
```

It's using `100vh` to calculate is incorrect, because in real website, we have header, sidebar, footer and some other elements, it will make the height of website longer.

What I want it only calculate height content of `<article>` tag, or maybe `id` of element, then use `<progress>` element, or `<amp-position-observer>` to trigger.

Thanks for your help!